# tmux and control sequence character issue

Tags: tmux

I try to resize terminal window from command line on my MacOSX

I can resize the width and heigh of the terminal with following command(Control Sequence Introducer CSI)

```
printf '\e[8;100;200t' "resize to 200x100
```

but when I use tmux in my terminal, then the command(printf '\e[8;100;200t' ) is not longer working

Any suggestion would be apprecaited.

Here is my tmux config file:

```
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"  #Reload with ctrl-r
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi                       #copy-mode vim-like 
set -g prefix `                                         #prefix from ctrl-b to ctrl-a
unbind C-b                                              #allow ctrl-b for other things
set -sg escape-time 1                                   #quicker responses
bind ` send-prefix                                      #Pass on ctrl-a for other apps
set -g base-index 1                                     #Numbering of windows
setw -g pane-base-index 1                               #Numbering of Panes
bind \ split-window -v                                  #Split panes horizontal
bind v split-window -h                                  #Split panes vertically

unbind-key j
bind-key j select-pane -D # Similar to 'C-w j' to navigate windows in Vim
unbind-key k
bind-key k select-pane -U
unbind-key h
bind-key h select-pane -L
unbind-key l
bind-key l select-pane -R

unbind-key Left 
bind-key  Left resize-pane -L 10 
unbind-key Right 
bind-key  Right resize-pane -R 10 
unbind-key Up 
bind-key  Up resize-pane -U 10 

unbind-key Down 
bind-key  Down resize-pane -D 10 

set -g window-status-current-style fg=red
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /bin/bash"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The escape sequence is being interpreted by tmux and is not being passed through to the terminal program that tmux is running in. To have it pass through, you need to wrap the escape sequence to tell tmux to pass it through:

```
printf '\ePtmux;\e%s\e\\' "${escape_sequence}"
```

where the variable `$escape_sequence` is the sequence you want tmux to pass out to the terminal. For example, the sequence in the original question would become

```
printf '\ePtmux;\e\e[8;100;200t\e\\'
```

There is not much documentation for this, but evidence can be found in the CHANGES file for the 1.5 release: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/1.5/CHANGES#L33

Comment: sorry, what is the full command to warp escape_sequence: printf '\e[8;100;200t'

Comment: Could you put the FULL command so that I can try it on my terminal?